# Spring PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer Issue to Load A Properties File

Tags: java, spring

I'm trying to use an external properties file to populate some of the beans in my Spring Application Context configuration file. When I don't use the ${} properties and hardcode the jpaVendorAdapter class property below, I can see the file is loaded in the log file. If u rely on the properties file and use the class="${jpa.vendor.adapter}" notation, I get the Cannot find class [${jpa.vendor.adapter}] for bean with name 'jpaVendorAdapter' defined in class path resource [spring/applicationContext.xml]; exception. The file is definetly on the classpath at runtime, it just seems like its loaded after its needed. I've also tried using the *`<contextroperty-placeholder/>`* approach, but got the same exception. I'm using Spring version 3.2.2.RELEASE, any ideas?

### ApplicationContext.xml

```xml
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
        xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa" xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
        xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.0.xsd">

    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
            <property name="location">
                <value>classpath:runtime/project.properties</value>
            </property>
        </bean>
    <bean id="jpaVendorAdapter" class="${jpa.vendor.adapter}">
        <property name="showSql" value="true" />
        <property name="generateDdl" value="true" />
        <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect" />
    </bean>
    </beans>
```

### project.properties

```
jpa.vendor.adapter=org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter
```

### Exception

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [${jpa.vendor.adapter}] for bean with name 'jpaVendorAdapter' defined in class path resource [spring/applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ${jpa.vendor.adapter}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1269) ~[spring-beans-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:578) ~[spring-beans-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1338) ~[spring-beans-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:356) [spring-beans-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:327) [spring-beans-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:435) [spring-beans-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:624) [spring-context-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:461) [spring-context-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:389) [spring-web-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294) [spring-web-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112) [spring-web-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.spring.SpringContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(SpringContextLoaderListener.java:44) [resteasy-spring-2.3.5.Final.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:740) [jetty-server-7.6.8.v20121106.jar:7.6.8.v20121106]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:238) [jetty-servlet-7.6.8.v20121106.jar:7.6.8.v20121106]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1238) [jetty-webapp-7.6.8.v20121106.jar:7.6.8.v20121106]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:683) [jetty-server-7.6.8.v20121106.jar:7.6.8.v20121106]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:480) [jetty-webapp-7.6.8.v20121106.jar:7.6.8.v20121106]
    at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.JettyWebAppContext.doStart(JettyWebAppContext.java:256) [jetty-maven-plugin-7.6.8.v20121106.jar:7.6.8.v20121106]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64) [jetty-util-7.6.8.v20121106.jar:7.6.8.v20121106]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:229) [jetty-server-7.6.8.v20121106.jar:7.6.8.v20121106]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:172) [jetty-server-7.6.8.v20121106.jar:7.6.8.v20121106]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64) [jetty-util-7.6.8.v20121106.jar:7.6.8.v20121106]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:229) [jetty-server-7.6.8.v20121106.jar:7.6.8.v20121106]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64) [jetty-util-7.6.8.v20121106.jar:7.6.8.v20121106]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:95) [jetty-server-7.6.8.v20121106.jar:7.6.8.v20121106]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:275) [jetty-server-7.6.8.v20121106.jar:7.6.8.v20121106]
    at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.JettyServer.doStart(JettyServer.java:65) [jetty-maven-plugin-7.6.8.v20121106.jar:7.6.8.v20121106]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64) [jetty-util-7.6.8.v20121106.jar:7.6.8.v20121106]
    at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.startJetty(AbstractJettyMojo.java:511) [jetty-maven-plugin-7.6.8.v20121106.jar:7.6.8.v20121106]
    at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.execute(AbstractJettyMojo.java:364) [jetty-maven-plugin-7.6.8.v20121106.jar:7.6.8.v20121106]
    at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.JettyRunMojo.execute(JettyRunMojo.java:521) [jetty-maven-plugin-7.6.8.v20121106.jar:7.6.8.v20121106]
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101) [maven-core-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209) [maven-core-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153) [maven-core-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145) [maven-core-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84) [maven-core-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59) [maven-core-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183) [maven-core-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161) [maven-core-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:319) [maven-core-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156) [maven-core-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537) [maven-embedder-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196) [maven-embedder-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141) [maven-embedder-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.6.0_51]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) ~[na:1.6.0_51]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) ~[na:1.6.0_51]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) ~[na:1.6.0_51]
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290) [plexus-classworlds-2.4.jar:na]
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230) [plexus-classworlds-2.4.jar:na]
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409) [plexus-classworlds-2.4.jar:na]
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352) [plexus-classworlds-2.4.jar:na]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ${jpa.vendor.adapter}
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50) ~[na:na]
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:244) ~[na:na]
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:230) ~[na:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:430) ~[na:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:383) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:260) ~[spring-core-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:416) ~[spring-beans-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1290) ~[spring-beans-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1261) ~[spring-beans-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
    ... 51 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing the `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` bean declaration with

```xml
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:/runtime/project.properties"/>
```

The above must not work with `class` attribute.

What you can do instead is implement a [`FactoryBean`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/FactoryBean.html) that produces your class type

```xml
<bean id="example" class="com.mycom.factory.JpaVendorAdapterFactory">
   <property name="class" value="${jpa.vendor.adapter}"/>
   <property name="showSql" value="true" />
   <property name="generateDdl" value="true" />
   <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect" />
</bean>
```

I believe Spring will automatically call `getObject()` on this bean and add the returned object to the context. I do believe `example` will be the name for the generated bean (not the factory).

Comment: I want to load multiple files and based on what environment the web app is in it will load the file based on a jvm param and overload the base properties file. That is why I want to use the PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer and eventually pass it a list of properties files.  I first have to get it to ready one file though.

Comment: That has nothing to do with Maven. Maven is a build system. If you want to do something at runtime, you probably want to look into Spring `Profiles`.

Comment: I changed the title a bit, you're correct its not a maven issue but a spring issue.

Comment: @c12 Try with a `context:property-placeholder` declaration.

Comment: I tried both  <context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:project.properties"/> and <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:runtime/project.properties"/> same exception for both

Comment: using this method, it seems like the ${jpa.vendor.adapter} is read in before the properties files are loaded.  If I remove the ${jpa.vendor.adapter} and hardcode it I can see in the log that the file is loaded.

Comment: @ct2 Are you sure you don't have anything else interfering? Maybe another PropertyPlaceholder?

Comment: it looks like I'm able to populate other attributes of the Spring Application Context, just not one's that are ..."class=${property.value}" Have you ever populated something like that before from a properties file?  Maybe its not supported..

Comment: @c12 You are probably correct, but I can't find docs for it. I've added a workaround to my answer.

Comment: It might be the issue with Spring version, when I tried with 3.2.4 it worked this way: context:property-placeholder  ,  instead of using 'PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer'.

Answer (score 1):

Try this Spring config instead:

```xml
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath*:project.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: For reference, see section 4.7.2 here: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/resources.html

Comment: sorry false alarm, I didn't fully test it. It still throws the same exception

Comment: classpath:/**/project.properties?

Comment: @bellabax - using this method, it seems like the ${jpa.vendor.adapter} is read in before the properties files are loaded. If I remove the ${jpa.vendor.adapter} and hardcode it I can see in the log that the properties file is loaded.

Comment: I can't try myself but add id to ppholder bean and depends-on to ppholder?